# Placeholder text for Dropdown with Chosen in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I'm using `chosen` for `rails`, but can't set the placeholder text for my dropdown menus.

I've tried `:allow_blank => "Please pick one"` and `prompt: "take a card"`, but both of them add the placeholder text as a selectable option in the dropdown. Documentation is a bit squirrely and can't seem to find good documentation for the rails adoption.

**gems:**

```
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails', github: 'duncanparkinson/chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails' # dependency versions less stringent
```

**Currently have:**

`= f.input :applying_as, collection: @my_collection, prompt: "test"`

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with placeholder:

```
f.input :applying_as, input_html: { "data-placeholder" => "..." }
```

or

```
f.input :applying_as, input_html: {data: { placeholder: "..." }}
```

depending on your preferences and whether you have other data attributes to add.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".chosen").data("placeholder","Select Frameworks...").chosen();
});
```

[reference](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen)

Comment: I'd rather set it to the label of whatever attribute I'm using, obviously dynamically through ruby. Is there a way to do this?